# wxPython: switching text control focus on tab press

Tags: python, wxpython

I made a frame that asks the user to put in a bunch of information in several text control fields. How can I make it so that when you hit the 'tab' key your cursor moves to the next text control?

Comment: The code is pretty ugly but basically I have a frame with a ScrolledWindow on it, and a bunch of nested BoxSizers, some of which have TextCtrls in them.

Answer (score 2):

If you put a wx.Panel as the only child of the ScrolledWindow and put the other widgets on the panel, then it should work automatically. You could also use ScrolledPanel instead.